# PowerShell Email Attachment: Could not find file 'D:\20201124131044\TRACS-20201124034849\error.log environment.log RACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to send out an email with only the attachments that exist in the directory. There are three sets of files i am monitoring: error.log, environment.log and a .stdout. I want to check whether each one of the files exist and if they do then add it in a list and send it out as attachments. I dont want to do anything if the files dont exist. I attempted to loop through the list of files (this is in windows) and then if the files exist send them out. My code below:

```
$PSEmailServer = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$Password ="xxxxxxxxx"
$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxxxx", $mypassword)
$EmailSubject ="test"
$filepath ="D:\20201124131044\TRACS-20201124034849\"
$files = @('error.log','environment.log','TRACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout')
$FromEmail ="xxxxxxxxxx"     


if(($files | foreach{Test-path $filepath }) -contains $True){

$newfile = $filepath  + $files
Send-MailMessage -From $FromEmail -To "xxxxxxx" -Subject $EmailSubject -Body "test" -Credential $mycredential -Attachments $newfile
}
 else {
  echo "nothing"
  exit
 }
```

when i run the above i get the following error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 'D:\20201124131044\TRACS-20201124034849\error.log environment.log TRACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout'. At C:\Users\Downloads\powershell.ps1:22 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $FromEmail -To "xxxxxxx" -Subje ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : > System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

I think I need to iterate the list to attach each filename to the it's filepath and then store it in a list and then send out the email? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `-contains` or `-in` to find filenames in an array.
Also, I would recommend using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for the parameters to Send-MailMessage:

```
$filepath = "D:\20201124131044\TRACS-20201124034849"
$files    = 'error.log','environment.log','TRACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout'

# find files with names that can be found in the $files array
$attachments = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -File | Where-Object { $files -contains $_.Name })

# if we have any files to send
if ($attachments.Count) {
    $Password     = "xxxxxxxxx"
    $mypassword   = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxxxx", $mypassword)
    # use splatting for better readability
    $mailParams = @{
        To          = "xxxxxxx"
        From        = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        Subject     = "test"
        Body        = "test"
        Credential  = $mycredential
        Attachments = $attachments.FullName
        SmtpServer  = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        # more parameters can be added here
    }
    # send the email
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
else {
    Write-Host 'Nothing to send..'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$PSEmailServer = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$Password ="xxxxxxxxx"
$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxxxx", $mypassword)
$EmailSubject ="test"
$attachments = Get-ChildItem "D:\20201124131044\TRACS-20201124034849" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "error.log|environment.log|TRACS-20201124034849.sterr.stdout"}
$FromEmail ="xxxxxxxxxx"     


if($attachments){      
Send-MailMessage -From $FromEmail -To "xxxxxxx" -Subject $EmailSubject -Body "test" -Credential $mycredential -Attachments $attachements
}
 else {
  echo "nothing"
  exit
 }
```

Comment: `-match` uses regex, so you need to escape the special characters in the filenames (the dot) with a backslash

Comment: You are correct, I think PowerShell is handling that, I tried in my computer and it worked without escaping the characters!

Comment: No, PowerShell does not _handle that_. In regex, the dot means "any single character", so your match would also pass 'errorXlog'. Because you also do not anchor the options, a crazy filename like 'blah123errorQlog789.xyz' would pass the match